# How To Export channel entries with Grid information

Tags: channel-entries, grid, export

We have Export Entries by code but We don't know format OF CSV how to store grid information in CSV FILE. also any one have idea for Export channel entries with grid information then let me know .

Thanks,
Zeal PD

Answer (score 1):

One quick and dirty way is to output the data into a template then copy/paste the data into a text editor and save as a .csv

1. Create a template in EE that you'll use to output the data
2. Add a channel entries tag to get the data, something like this:

   {exp:channel:entries channel="my_channel" limit="999" status="open|closed" dynamic="no}
   {entry_id}|{status}|{title}|{custom_field}|{grid_field}{grid_field:fieldname1}, {grid_field:fieldname2}{/grid_field}
   {/exp:channel:entries}
3. Call up the template in your browser and copy the output.

You'll note that I use pipe separators and commas to separate grid field values in this example. You'll need to modify it to get the format you want.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into using either [Export It](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/export-it) or [AJW Export](https://devot-ee.com/add-ons/ajw-export). I have personally used ajw-export it exports to csv. However you'll need to write sql queries.